# How do I check if a string starts with a negative number and a float? [python]

Tags: python

I have a piece of code that looks something like this:

```
    loc2 = {}
    with open('loc.txt') as filename:
    for line in filename:
        a = line.strip()
        if a.replace('.','',1).isdigit():
            loc2[float(a[0])] = a[1:]
    return loc2
```

in which I need to check if a number [which is always at the start of the line in file loc.txt, and always alone on the entire line] that can be either a negative, an int or a float, and add it to a dictionary as a key. Could someone help me out please? Not sure how to approach this. I tried replacing the '.' with empty space, but it didn't work, and also didn't fix my negative numbers problem, obviously. I'm a noob in python still. Thanks!

example of loc.txt:

```
1
stuff
1.1
stuff
-4
stuff
```

where stuff is things that will be added to the dictionary as values later on.

Comment: Can you please provide file `loc.txt` as an example?

Comment: Are all the lines just numbers? What should the value be for the entry in the dict where the key is the parsed number?

Comment: @bla, yes of course. sorry

Comment: @crescent1033, I think the solution proposed by @MikePeder is very similar to what you need. I would just change `loc2[k] = ' '.join(a[1:])` to `loc2[k] = None` so there is "nothing" on your dict's values.

Comment: @crescent1033 If you have a new question please dont edit your current question, **post a new question** instead, thanks.

Comment: When you have a different question, please ask a new question. Don't edit an existing question to ask about something completely different.

Comment: Oops, my bad, that happened by accident. I'm very new here.

Comment: However, the answer is short: JDK is the complete toolkit of Java (all executables Java offers, like a compiler, the JVM itself, some anaylze tools, ...). The JVM is just the virtual machine, which is the program that can read Java byte code and actually executes it. So the JVM is the core of Java, it interprets Java and executes the statements. Be aware that StackOverflow expects you to do research before you ask questions. So a question like this would probably get down-voted due to lack of research since a quick google search would clarify the difference between both terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using a try except statement.

```
loc2 = {}
with open('loc.txt') as filename:
    for i,line in enumerate(filename):
        # split the given line up by space into a list
        a = line.strip().split()
        try:
            # attempt to convert first part of line into float
            k = float(a[0])
            # assignment that key the value of the rest of the string
            loc2[k] = ' '.join(a[1:])
        except ValueError as ex:
            # actions performed when the line does not start with number
            print('Line %d did not start with a number.'%i)
        else:
            # actions performed when the float conversion was successful
            print('Key {} has been added with value: {}'.format(k,loc2[k]))
```

**loc.txt file:**

```
-1 one
0 two
1.5 three
-5.708 four
test
```

**Ouput:**

```
Key -1.0 has been added with value: one
Key 0.0 has been added with value: two
Key 1.5 has been added with value: three
Key -5.708 has been added with value: four
Line 4 did not start with a number.
```

**loc2 contents**

```
{-1.0: 'one', 0.0: 'two', 1.5: 'three', -5.708: 'four'}
```